# spring - exposing SimpleMessageListenerContainer created from factory as mbean

Tags: spring, spring-jmx

Using spring 4. I am creating a

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer
```

from a factory method with

```
@Configuration @Bean

        @Bean( name = "container" )
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(){
...
...
```

How to expose this instance on JMX? Since @ManagedResource can only be applied on class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public MBeanExporter exporter() {
    MBeanExporter mBeanExporter = new MBeanExporter();
    mBeanExporter.setBeans(
        Collections.singletonMap("myDomain:type=container,name=myContainter", "container"));
    return mBeanExporter;
}
```

That will expose all the public methods/attributes. If you wish to limit which are exposed you can use a [`MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-interface-methodnames):

```
@Bean
public MBeanExporter exporter() {
    MBeanExporter mBeanExporter = new MBeanExporter();
    mBeanExporter.setBeans(
        Collections.singletonMap("myDomain:type=container,name=myContainter", "container"));
    MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler assembler = new MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler();
    assembler.setManagedMethods(new String[] { "start", "stop" });
    mBeanExporter.setAssembler(assembler);
    return mBeanExporter;
}
```